# Elactic Search Not Reciving Data from logstash

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, elastic-stack, logstash-configuration

I have a ELastic Search server:

```
    {
  "cluster_name" : "elasticsearch",
  "status" : "yellow",
  "timed_out" : false,
  "number_of_nodes" : 76,
  "number_of_data_nodes" : 1,
  "active_primary_shards" : 297,
  "active_shards" : 297,
  "relocating_shards" : 0,
  "initializing_shards" : 0,
  "unassigned_shards" : 297,
  "delayed_unassigned_shards" : 0,
  "number_of_pending_tasks" : 0,
  "number_of_in_flight_fetch" : 0
}
```

It is running on a dual core machine with 30gb Ram and is receiving logs from 3 to 4 logstash servers and has a total of 30 input (all log-stash servers combined) but for most inputs the logs are getting missed and i get no log for 30-40 mins and i get warning in logstash server like `:retrying-failed-action-with-response-code-429`.Also the Elastic search server has a very high ram usage.The heartbeat of the log files is very high..I have checked gork patter and they are correct 
This is one of my conf files:

```
 input {

  exec {
    command => "/usr/bin/touch /var/run/logstash-monit/input.touch && /bin/echo OK."
    interval => 60
    type => "heartbeat"
  }

  file {
    type => 'seller-forever'
   path => '/var/log/seller/seller.log'
   sincedb_path => "/opt/logstash/sincedb-access1"
    }
    }
filter {

grok {
   type => "seller-forever"
    match => [ "message", "%{GREEDYDATA:logline} %{GREEDYDATA:extra_fields}" ]
  }

geoip {
        add_tag => [ "GeoIP" ]
        database => "/opt/logstash/GeoLiteCity.dat"
        source => "clientip"
    }
    if [useragent] != "-" and [useragent] != "" {
      useragent {
        add_tag => [ "UA" ]
        source => "useragent"
      }
    }
    if [bytes] == 0 { mutate { remove => "[bytes]" } }
    if [geoip][city_name]      == "" { mutate { remove => "[geoip][city_name]" } }
    if [geoip][continent_code] == "" { mutate { remove => "[geoip][continent_code]" } }
    if [geoip][country_code2]  == "" { mutate { remove => "[geoip][country_code2]" } }
    if [geoip][country_code3]  == "" { mutate { remove => "[geoip][country_code3]" } }
    if [geoip][country_name]   == "" { mutate { remove => "[geoip][country_name]" } }
    if [geoip][latitude]       == "" { mutate { remove => "[geoip][latitude]" } }
    if [geoip][longitude]      == "" { mutate { remove => "[geoip][longitude]" } }
    if [geoip][postal_code]    == "" { mutate { remove => "[geoip][postal_code]" } }
    if [geoip][region_name]    == "" { mutate { remove => "[geoip][region_name]" } }
    if [geoip][time_zone]      == "" { mutate { remove => "[geoip][time_zone]" } }
    if [urlquery]              == "" { mutate { remove => "urlquery" } }

    if "apache_json" in [tags] {
       if [method]    =~ "(HEAD|OPTIONS)" { mutate { remove => "method" } }
        if [useragent] == "-"              { mutate { remove => "useragent" } }
        if [referer]   == "-"              { mutate { remove => "referer" } }
    }
    if "UA" in [tags] {
        if [device] == "Other" { mutate { remove => "device" } }
        if [name]   == "Other" { mutate { remove => "name" } }
        if [os]     == "Other" { mutate { remove => "os" } }
    }

}


output {

stdout { codec => rubydebug }

elasticsearch {
type => "seller-forever"
index => "seller-forever"
host => "10.0.0.89"
protocol => "node"
   }
}
```

I am using kibana for visualization . 
How should i go about fixing this what things should i check ? Any Help would be appreciated i am not able to understand what to do.

Comment: check into the error log of logstash , in /var/log/logstash/

Comment: @NishantSingh nothing in logstash.log ,this is what in found in logstash.err 
May 14, 2016 10:28:35 AM `org.elasticsearch.cluster.service.InternalClusterService$UpdateTask run
INFO: [logstash-ip-10-0-0-105-8431-13990] added {[logstash-ip-10-0-0-105-6096-13970][M-skGUKgQXC-_Zt9kHma6w][ip-10-0-0-105][inet[/10.0.0.105:9303]]{client=true, data=false},}, reason: zen-disco-receive(from master [[Hammer Harrison][GPRbvuZ4RJW_Cq_iPW1i7A][ip-10-0-0-89][inet[/10.0.0.89:9300]]])`

Comment: 429 code means your Logstash clients are sending too many requests and the node is not able to handle them.

Answer (score 1):

Did you check your Logstash and Elasticsearch logs?

On the other hand i have rewritten your logstash config because some of the options you use were obsolete or deprecated with my Logstash version 2.3.2.

I changed remove in mutate to remov_field (remove is deprecated).
I removed protocol because it is obsolete (node is the default option).

Type in grok and elasticsearch is obsolete.
You have the correct type in your input so Logstash will send it with your files.
If you want to do something based on a specific type in the filter. You need to use something like this.

```
filter {
    if [type] == "apacheAccess" {
        grok {
            match => [ "message", "%{message}" ]
        }
```

You can fix your unassigned_shards with 2 options.

1. You can force a merge this well force a merge of one or more indices.
   `curl -XPOST 'http://localhost:9200/_forcemerge'` [Elasticsearch Documentation: Force Merge](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.3/indices-forcemerge.html)
2. You can set your index.routing.allocation.disable_allocation to false. This will disable allocations. `curl -XPUT 'localhost:9200/_settings' \ -d '{"index.routing.allocation.disable_allocation": false}'`